# Update TextViews AND Google Maps in same activity with service binder

Tags: android, google-maps, service, gps, handler

I have an activity with some TextViews that I update with current values from my service that runs in the background.
Thats working fine if I only update the TextViews.
I am getting also current LAT and LONG from the service to the activity, cause I am recording the driven distance in the background.

Now I want to show a small map under my values, so that I could see where I am.
But when I add the map, the TextViews are getting updated only one time, until the map starts I think. Only the map is updating, but the TextViews no longer.

What I am doing wrong?

My service binder in my activity:

```
// Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(Dashboard.this, GPSService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            try{
                if (mService.StartadressFlag==1){
                    doUpdate(); //This updates the TextViews with values from service
                    callMap(); //This calls the map with LAT and LONG from service
                }
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_UPDATE, UPDATE_RATE_IN_MS);
            }
            catch(final Exception ex){
                //damn
                Log.e("Dashboard", "Error in activity", ex);  // log the error
            }

        }
    };
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    // enable Street view by default
    mapView.setStreetView(true);      
    // enable to show Satellite view
    // mapView.setSatellite(true);
    // enable to show Traffic on map
    // mapView.setTraffic(true);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);     
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(16);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured it out by myself.
I have added a own GPS-Listener in my activity for the map. So I do not need to get the LAT and LONG in the binder for the map. Then everything is working fine.